# C#: Is there a LINQ way to create an array of objects given an array of constructor parameters?

Tags: c#, linq

As an example, say I have an array of names and I want to create an array of `Person` objects by calling a constructor that takes `string name`.

```
class Person()
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}

...

static void Main()
{
    string[] names = {"Peter", "Paul", "Mary"};
    Person[] people;

    /*  I could do this but I'm wondering if there's a better way. */
    List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
    foreach(string name in names)
    {
        persons.Add(new Person(name));
    }

    people = persons.ToArray();
}
```

I've been stuck in the .Net 2.0 world for too long now and I'm trying to modernize in my current downtime...

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
// names is string[]
Person[] people = names.Select(s => new Person(s)).ToArray();
```

Explanation:

[`Enumerable.Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select.aspx) is the LINQ method for projection. That is, taking a sequence of `Foo`s and projecting them to `Bar`s via some rule `Func<Foo, Bar>` that eats `Foo`s and spits out `Bar`s. Thus

```
names.Select(s => new Person(s))
```

is a projection of the sequence `names` of type `IEnumerable<string>` to a sequence of type `IEnumerable<Person>`. If you know functional programming it plays the role of `map`.

Now, there is a subtle point here that is worth understanding; this is almost surely one of the most important yet easily misunderstood aspects of LINQ. This is the concept of deferred execution. When we say

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = names.Select(s => new Person(s));
```

this does not actually perform the projection (i.e., it does not yet create the instances of `Person` constructed using the `string`s in `names` as constructor parameters). Instead, it creates something that captures the rule of how to project the sequence `names` into a sequence of `Person`. It's only when that rule (known as an iterator) is actually executed does the projection take place.

One way to cause this execution to occur is to use the method [`Enumerable.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) which basically says iterate through the sequence and give me back the results as an array.

There are other ways to cause the execution to occur. For example

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = names.Select(s => new Person(s)); 
foreach(Person p in persons) {
    Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
}
```

or

```
IEnumerable<Person> persons = names.Select(s => new Person(s)); 
Person p = persons.First();
```

which would execute the "first" projection (i.e., `new Person(names[0]`)) and assign the result to `p`.

Of course, this doesn't even get into exactly what

```
s => new Person(s)
```

is. That's a lambda expression, and you can get an introduction to them in my answer to [How does this LINQ Expression work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106634/how-does-this-linq-expression-work/2106646#2106646).

Comment: I get confused now seeing `Select` instead of `map` like in F#.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Yes, I would love to know why the more familiar `map` and `fold` weren't used instead of `Select` and `Aggregate`, for example.

Comment: @Jason, map and fold are actually not the most familiar to most developers, most developers come from a SQL world, where aggregation and selection rule the syntax.

Comment: @Jason...+1 for you answer though, very nice indeed.

Comment: The thing with deferred execution is called *thunk*.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting this incase someone else needs a light on a slightly different scenario. This was my case, and I used Jason's answer to get there.

Imagine you have a class with the person's name, and job title, and you want to fill that object:

```
public class Employee
{
   private string name;
   private string jobTitle;

   public Employee(){}
   public Employee(string name, string job)
   {
     this.name = name;
     this.jobTitle = job;
   }

  //  getters + setters...
}
```

Then you'd do

```
var IQueryable<Employee> list = from p in context.Persons 
                                join j in context.Jobs
                                  on p.jobId == j.jobId
                                select new Employee(p.Name, j.Title);
```

Then you'll loop through the list to get the instances