# Convert string to int array using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a function (tointarray) to convert a string into an array of ints, but I am not very satisfied with it. It does the job, but there must be a more elegant way to do this, and perhaps [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query) could help here. Unfortunately I am not very good in LINQ. Is there a better way?

My function:

```
{
    string s1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12";
    int[] ia = tointarray(s1, ';');
}
int[] tointarray(string value, char sep)
{
    string[] sa = value.Split(sep);
    int[] ia = new int[sa.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < ia.Length; ++i)
    {
        int j;
        string s = sa[i];
        if (int.TryParse(s, out j))
        {
            ia[i] = j;
        }
    }
    return ia;
}
```

Answer (score 234, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113115/c-is-there-a-linq-way-to-create-an-array-of-objects-given-an-array-of-construc) post asked a similar question and used LINQ to solve it, maybe it will help you out too.

```
string s1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12";
int[] ia = s1.Split(';').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

Comment: langs.Split(';').Select(int.Parse).ToArray()

Comment: Convert.ToInt32('1') returns 49 :) not 1 :)

Comment: Calling Convert.ToInt32 won't convert the number , it will convert the character code-point instead... review you answer :D

Answer (score 41):

You can shorten JSprangs solution a bit by using a method group instead:

```
string s1 = "1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12";
int[] ints = s1.Split(';').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 19):

```
s1.Split(';').Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
```

<strike>Untested and off the top of my head...testing now for correct syntax.</strike>

Tested and everything looks good.

Comment: Can't you just do: `s1.Split(';').Select(Convert.ToInt32).ToArray();`

Comment: @strager - No, that statement doesn't compile.

Comment: @strager, apparently you cannot to that using .Net 4.0. You are dreaming in Python ;)

Comment: Nah, I've been spending too much time with Javascript.  =]

Comment: It usually does work, since the method name will be cast to the correct Func/predicate/delegate. The reason it doesn't work with Convert.ToInt32 is because of the Convert(string,int) overload that confuses the type inference. `s1.Split(';').Select((Func<string,int>)Convert.ToInt32).ToArray()` works correctly, but isn't really any less code

Comment: Anyway the given implementation isn't correct since unlike given sample it fail on inputs that contains non integer strings.

Comment: @Jakub - Depending on how you truly want the code to function, this might be exactly what you're looking for. Not everybody wants arbitrary zeros in their results.

Comment: @Justin: Right, but I couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 19):

Actually correct one to one implementation is:

```
int n;
int[] ia = s1.Split(';').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out n) ? n : 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Use `int[] ia = s1.Split(';').Select(s => int.TryParse(s, out int n) ? n : 0).ToArray();` for single line.

Answer (score 8):

Here's code that filters out invalid fields:

```
    var ints = from field in s1.Split(';').Where((x) => { int dummy; return Int32.TryParse(x, out dummy); })
               select Int32.Parse(field);
```

Comment: +1 I kept scrolling trying to find the solution equivalent to the OPs code. Unfortunately this is less efficient since it has to parse the int twice.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static int[] ConvertArray(string[] arrayToConvert)
    {
        int[] resultingArray = new int[arrayToConvert.Length];

        int itemValue;

        resultingArray = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>
            (
                arrayToConvert, 
                delegate(string intParameter) 
                {
                    int.TryParse(intParameter, out itemValue);
                    return itemValue;
                }
            );

        return resultingArray;
    }
```

Reference:

http://codepolice.net/convert-string-array-to-int-array-and-vice-versa-in-c/