# Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'

Tags: c#, .net

```
string[] weight = txtProductOptn1.Text.Split(',');
var Weight1 = Convert.ToInt32(weight);
```

Getting an error when i am converting the string array to int or decimal as

> *Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type
>   'System.IConvertible'.*

Please  find the answer.

Comment: _Please find the answer.._ Hmm.

Comment: `var Weight1 = weight.Sum(i => Int32.Parse(i));` ? Can you tell us exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 6):

Try this, `weight` is an array. Assuming you want to convert first element of array.

```
string[] weight = txtProductOptn1.Text.Split(',');
var Weight1 = Convert.ToInt32(weight[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot convert a `string[]` to an `int`. Perhaps you want to convert every single string to an int:

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = weight.Select(int.Parse);
```

Note that this will fail if one of the strings is not parsable to int because it has an invalid format.

Answer (score 1):

You can't convert an array of string (`string[]`) to an integer (`int`).
Using `System.Linq`, you can try:

```
int[] convertedWeight = txtProductOptn1.Text.Split(',')
                                            .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x))
                                            .ToArray();
```

to convert each element to an integer.

I found a similar post here : [Convert string to int array using LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959161/linq-convert-string-to-int-array)