# Windows Phone 8 Convert string to an array of int

Tags: windows-phone-8, portable-class-library

how to convert a string to an array of int 
string mystring= "1,2,3,4";
int myArrayOfInt=[1,2,3,4];

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959161/linq-convert-string-to-int-array) may help you.

Comment: Thx Romasz but I Can not use Array.Select in PCL !!!

Answer (score 0):

This code would provide you array of int:

```
string source = "1,2,3,4";
var stringArray = source.Split(',');
var ArrayOfInt = stringArray.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Comment: intead comment provide tag

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] myArrayOfInt = mystring.Split(',').Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n)).ToArray();
```

but you cannot use linq in plc so:

```
var arrOfStr = mystring.Split(',');
int[] myArrayOfInt = new int()[arrOfStr.Length];

for(int i = 0; i < arrOfStr.Length; i++)
{
   myArrayOfInt[i] = Convert.ToInt32(arrOfStr[i]);
}
```

something like this?

Comment: I've tried the second but I would like to use more elegant way :)

Comment: Well portability comes with limitations, so I do not think there is a more elegant way.

Comment: @Samissa You should be able to use LINQ in PCLs.  What are the targets for your PCLs?

Comment: WP8.0 .Net4.5,Windows Store apps