# C# - Using numbers split from lines in text file

Tags: c#, split

I'm making a basic tax calculator which has to read from two lines in a text file using ReadLines, then split() these by the comma and use these numbers for calculations. I can read and split the file fine, but actually referencing the split data for use in calculations isn't working as I'd hoped.
The text file is something like this:

```
500, 600, 700, 800, 900
0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5
```

And this is my code so far:

```
private void btnCalculateEmployeeTax_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] rates = File.ReadLines(@"E:\\path.txt").ToArray();

        string str1 = rates[0], str2 = rates[1];

        string[] income = str1.Split(',');
        string[] tax = str2.Split(',');

        int wages = 40*int.Parse(txtHourlyRate.Text);

        if (wages < income[0])
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Less than 500");
            MessageBox.Show ("Total tax is $" + (wages*tax[0]));

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("More than 500");
        }
```

Obviously it's the code within the if/else statement that is kicking the error - this just gives you an idea of how I want to use the numbers. Is there a way to assign each number from the text file to a local variable? Or is there a work around for what I'm attempting here?

Apologies in advance for the rookie question.

Comment: What does "calculations isn't working" mean? Explain what's wrong and what would be correct.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959161/convert-string-to-int-array-using-linq has copy-paste ready code for your split...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if you wanna fix this you need to conver `string` into `int`

```
 if (wages < int.Parse(income[0]))
 {
     MessageBox.Show("Less than 500");
     MessageBox.Show ("Total tax is $" + (wages*tax[0])); <- the same problem will be here
 }
```

But I think it will be better to create array of `double` instead of `string`

Comment: Thanks, yeah you're right. Income is working with Parse but:
'(wages * int.Parse(tax[0]))'
doesn't seem to work, yet it's been handled the same as income...?

Comment: @Onejo578 ok, I would recommend to you try this way look at https://dotnetfiddle.net/yxG3Xw and let me know if it fit to you. thanks

Comment: That cracked it! Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 1):

You can convert array to strings to array of ints.
You can do this like this

```
var result = income.Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
```

Comment: Good. but I think there should be `Double.Parse`.

Comment: One should use decimal instead of double for currency data types.  This avoids certain errors in converting between binary and denary fractional numbers.

I would recommend decimal.Parse() over double.Parse()