# Convert []string to int?

Tags: c#

I am trying to store a user input in a list. The user can enter numbers separated by a comma and then I need to perform some action based on the input that's why i am using IF later on and adding the input in a list. However if i try this then i cannot convert  []string to int .
I tried to use  `inputs.Add(Convert.ToInt32(separatedInput)); but i get that i am Unable to cast object of type 'System.String[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.'`

```
List<int> userDecision = new List<int>();
            Console.WriteLine("enter number separated by comma ");
            var userInputs = Console.ReadLine();
            var separatedInput = userInputs.Split(',');
            var inputs = new List<int>();
            inputs.Add(separatedInput);



            if (input == 1)
            {
                userDecision.Add(1);
            }
            if (input == 2)
            {
                userDecision.Add(2);
            }
            if (input == 3)
            {
                userDecision.Add(3);
            }
            if (input == 4)
            {
                userDecision.Add(4);
            }
            if (input == -1)
            {
                userDecision.Add(-1);
            }
```

Comment: That would need to parse the values to `int` `inputs.AddRange(separatedInput.Select(int.Parse))` though it will throw if any of the values cannot be parsed to `int`.

Comment: You're trying to add an array of strings (`separatedList`) to a list of integers, which doesn't make sense!

Comment: if you want to turn text in the form of e.g. `"123"` to a number, or in other words _parse_ it, use `int.Parse(...)`

Comment: @Sean well i know that, what is the other way to get more user values in a list ?

Comment: @VanessaKensington - if you know that then don't do it!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C#: Is there a LINQ way to create an array of objects given an array of constructor parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113115/c-is-there-a-linq-way-to-create-an-array-of-objects-given-an-array-of-construc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using *Linq* and *query* `userInput` into desired `List<int> userDecision` (let's get rid of temporary `separatedInput`, `input` and especially of batch of `if`s):

```
using System.Linq;

...         

Console.WriteLine("enter number separated by comma ");

List<int> userDecision = Console
  .ReadLine()
  .Split(',')
  .Select(item => (success : int.TryParse(item, out int value), 
                     input : value))
  .Where(record => record.success && 
                  (record.input == -1 || record.input >= 1 && record.input <= 4))
  .Select(record => record.input)
  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make your list of `int` by projecting the split `string[]`, using `int.Parse` and then `ToList`

```
var inputs = userInputs.Split(',').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Note that all the values MUST be parseable to an int, or the above line will fail.

Answer (score 1):

You need only below line of code.

```
List<int> userDecision= Array.ConvertAll(Console.ReadLine().Trim().Split(','),int.Parse).ToList<int>();
```